# text-decoration: none does not cancel out parent's text-decoration: underline

Tags: html, css

Here is a super simple question. I have some content that is underlined and some elements inside that need to *not* be underlined. I know there are plenty of workarounds for this (the myriad of different ways to underline everything else), but I feel like something below should be achievable. Is this desired behavior for a browser or is it a bug? Using Chrome.

Expected behavior is that "This is a" should be underlined and "test" should not be, but the whole thing is underlined. Result is that the whole sentence is underlined.

```html
<span style="text-decoration: underline">
This is a <span style="text-decoration: none">test</span>
</span>
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: This is standard behavior, parent styles take dominance in this instance. I'd suggest using `<u>` tag for those that need underlined.

Comment: EX: `<span><u>This is a</u> test<span>`

Comment: display:inline-block to the inner span